# How to map a complex Money Object in Entity Framework Core using HasConversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I have an issue with mapping a Money value object containing a Currency property of Enum type and Amount property of Decimal type to and from Entity Framework Core using HasConversion. The Money value object is used as Price property in a products table, as shown below:

```
public class Product : AggregateRoot<ProductId>
{
    protected Product(ProductId id, Money price) : base(id)
    {
        Price = price;
    }

    public static Product Register(Money price)
    {
        return new Product(new ProductId(Guid.NewGuid()), price);
    }

    public Money? Price { get; private set; }
}
```

And the Money ValueObject class is defined as next:

```
public class Money : CSharpFunctionalExtensions.ValueObject<Money>
    {

        public decimal Amount { get; }
        public Currency Currency { get; }

        private Money(decimal amount, Currency currency)
        {
            Amount = amount;
            Currency = currency;
        }

        public static Result<Money> Create(decimal amount, Currency currency)
        {
            if(amount < 0)
            {
                return Result.Failure<Money>(BaseDomainErrors.General.ValueNotNegative(Resources.Money,amount.ToString()));
            }
            
            return Result.Success(new Money(amount, currency));
        }
```

And my configuration in EF Core is next:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(DbTableNames.Products);


        // Map the complex money value object (currency,amount) to product table and back to valueobject
        builder.Property(product => product.Price)
            // map the money value object into a primitive value in the db.
            // 2way mappings: value object > primitive value to be stored in db and primitive value stored in db > value object
            .HasConversion( v => new { Amount = v.Amount, Currency = v.Currency },
                            v => Money.Create(v.Amount, v.Currency).Value).HasColumnName("Price");

    }
```

Problem is , when i execute the code to create the table and mappings, i get next error:

The property 'Product.Price' is of type '<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal, Currency>' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Any clue ?

Thx for any response,

Emmanuel.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11948